# How to prevent the double click selection from "empty" place in chrome and safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I am facing a issue with my webpage. when user double click on empty space any where ( chrome / safari ) it simply select all the empty areas and highlighting. to avoid this i used this css property:

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  -moz-user-select     : none;
 -khtml-user-select   : none;
 -webkit-user-select  : none;
 -o-user-select       : none;
 user-select          : none;
}
```

Now i am not able to select the "text" too. this is very bad. how to make selectable became selectable and empty space avoided..?

any idea?

screen shot:

[image: screen shot]

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BmETp/)

Note: click on the table column. you can't select the text.

Comment: Are you getting empty selection problem on drag and drop? Give us a fiddle demo please?

Comment: Just open stack overflow in chrome and double click, you will get empty space selected.

Comment: fiddle added. (http://jsfiddle.net/BmETp/)

Comment: This is the timeout I'm talking about: [jsfiddle.net/BmETp/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/BmETp/3/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle double-click on web pages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517338/how-to-handle-double-click-on-web-pages)

Answer (score -1):

To prevent double click for empty space you can used the below script and the syles.

```
function clearSelection() {
    if(document.selection && document.selection.empty) {
        document.selection.empty();
    } else if(window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
    }
}
```

And for the Chrome and safari browser you can use the below styles.

```
 span.no_selection {    
   -webkit-user-select: none; /*(safari, chrome) webkit */
 }
```

I Hope it will work fine.

Comment: I can't use the webkit-user-select, because if i use, even i can't select the text too..

Answer (score -2):

**EDIT:** Look, here's what I'm talking about in action. On single-click, you can select text just fine. However, on double-click, the CSS rule, `-webkit-user-select: none;`, is activated, thus preventing selection of "empty space". Upon single-click event again, this rule is removed. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BmETp/3/)

`-webkit-user-select: none;` will disallow all attempts to click and select stuff on a webpage. That's behaving normally.

Double-clicking is not a common user action, so it's not worth worrying about. However, if you absolutely must try to do away with this, you could create an event listener for all clicks on the page, record its timestamp as a variable, set a length of time of about a second as a variable, and then check the next click to see if its timestamp happens to be more than a second since the last recorded click timestamp. If yes, e.preventDefault the event. If not, allow it.

Comment: Thanks for the down-votes. However, check this link out from a previously answered question: [stackoverflow.com/a/4517448/2997710](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4517448/2997710)

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but what the original poster is asking for is a solution to eliminate the highlight you get by double clicking blank whitespace areas of the site, while still being able to highlight text on the page.  You're answering his question with something that's totally irrelevant, which is probably why you're getting down-voted.

Comment: No, I'm not. This is standard behavior for a website. There is no CSS rule for a double-click. There is the jQuery method `dblclick`, but that's it. I'm saying if you 1.) record timestamp of first click and 2.) compare it to timestamp of next click, and 3.) disable second click IF the two timestamps are too close, it will effectively end double-clicking. Please explain: How is that irrelevant?

Comment: Simple, he's not asking to end double-clicking.

Comment: To clarify further, he's using the example of highlighting a word by double-clicking on the word itself (double click HERE to see an example). What he does not want is to allow the user to highlight a block element by double clicking on the white space that surrounds it. I can see how his question could come off a bit confusing, but it seems as though that's what he meant.

Comment: Why does it matter if a user highlights a block element by double-clicking on the white space that surrounds it? How is this an undesirable thing? What impact would this have on UX/UI? This *seems* irrelevant and pointless with no practical application whatsoever in modern web development. Am I wrong?

Comment: You're not wrong to think so, and I agree with you that there's little to no impact in UX. I'm just a guy clarifying what the user has been asking, no need for a further discussion.